# "Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode." error happens at ./node_modules /tar/tar.js:108:10

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm using sqlite3 in an environment with electron and typescript, but when I try to use it, I get the error as the title says (when electron start to running). Please let me know what to do...

The error is as follows.

```
error - ../node_modules/tar/tar.js:108:10
Syntax error: Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.

  106 | // values for the mode field
  107 | var modes =
> 108 |   { suid: 04000 // set uid on extraction
      |           ^
  109 |   , sgid: 02000 // set gid on extraction
  110 |   , svtx: 01000 // set restricted deletion flag on dirs on extraction
  111 |   , uread:  0400
```

My environment is as follows.

```
os: Windows10

---------cmd------------
node -v
> v14.2.0

npx electron -v
> v12.0.11

-------package.json-------
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "npm run rebuild && electron-builder install-app-deps",
  "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
},
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "sqlite3":"^5.0.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "electron": "12.0.2",   (different version to ↑...?)
  "typescript": "^4.2.3"
}
```

If I could do something like ignore strict mode only in tar.js, would that be a workaround...? Or do I need to do something different?

--

[edit]
As a test, I tried to use "npm i tar" to install the tar directly, although it was not installed directly originally. Then I got a different error. It seems that node-gyp and node-pre-gyp have gone wrong.
Perhaps, the problem is not with the "tar" version, but with the dependency between electron, windows and sqlite3. But I don't know how to make this dependency correct... This is going to be another problem...Thanks anyway,,

Comment: What version of the `tar` library is installed? You can check it in the `package-lock.json` file

Comment: "tar" version in package-lock.json is "2.2.2". I took a look and found it is required by "node-pre-gyp" and "node-gyp", not "sqlite3".

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to define an octal or a decimal number?

1. If for example `04000` is supposed to be an octal number, use the `0o` prefix:

```js
const x = 0o4000;
console.log(x); // 2028 in decimal
```

2. If `040000` is supposed to be a decimal number just use `4000`.

Comment: I don't want to define an octal or a decimal number. The error is occuring in node_modules which I don't write.  I think tar.js was used by sqlite3 and I don't know how to solve this error.

Comment: Well, the problem can be fixed by either fixing `tar.js` that is not compatible with JavaScript `strict mode` or by disabling `strict mode` in your build environment.

Comment: If `tar` is an npm module, you might also just try to upgrade to a newer version.